# How do I change my Sandbox account into a live account?

Tags: api, live, sandbox, payment

Our site is ready, but PayPal is still running in Test mode / Sandbox.

How do we make it live and take actually payments? Is this a setting PayPal-side?

CMS is Drupal 7.x

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are having `PayPalMode`,`PayPalApiUsername`,`PayPalApiPassword`,and `PayPalApiSignature` for test or sandbox mode. But to run on LIVE mode you need to again grab all the above mentioned details from the Real LIVE PayPal account.

Do let us know the Payment method you are using ! I am assuming for DoDirect Payment Method.

Just set `PayPalMode = 'live';`

Comment: Sorry, how do I find this out? On the CMS side of things all I need to enter is the PayPal business email address. But PayPal-side, where do I go to change / updates these details?

Comment: Which CMS you are using?

Comment: Follow the below links :
[link](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/paypal-standard)
[link](https://drupal.org/node/1902734)
Also see my answer

Answer (score 0):

On your site, at admin/commerce/config/payment-methods, edit your PayPal WPS settings.
Enter the email address of your real PayPal seller account.

Switch over from "sandbox" to "live", and I would also recommend switching off the debugging mode at this stage.

It is always best to test the live account is working properly by sending through a low-value order using your own credit card. You can then refund the order later if it works.

Hope this will works for you !

You can also follow the following 2 help links:

[Drupal Paypal Payment Standard](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/paypal-standard)
And
[Commerce PayPal Payments Advanced / Payflow Link](https://drupal.org/node/1902734)

Comment: Thank you. Now found it through Store/Configuration/Payment Methods and switching to live. How do I switch off debugging mode?